# Plotting points on a map

Tags: r, data-visualization

I am trying to plot coordinate points on a map, but I get the plot.new error. Could you please help?

```
library(maptools)
library(ggmap)
library(mapproj)    
table <- read.table("table.txt", header=TRUE, sep=",")
map <- get_map(location = 'France', zoom = 6, maptype = c("toner"))
points(table$LONG, table$LAT, pch=21, bg=color, cex=0.7, lwd=.4)
ggmap(map)
```

Here is an idea of what the table looks like:

```
CITY,LAT,LONG
Paris,48.856667,2.351944
Lyon,45.766944,4.834167
Bordeaux,44.838611,0.578334
```

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example. What are the objects `color` and `map`? In which packages can we find the functions `get_map` and `ggmap`?

Answer (score 3):

Try `geom_point`:

```
library(maptools)
library(ggmap)
library(mapproj)

city <- c("Paris", "Lyon", "Bordeaux")
my.lat <- c(48.856667, 45.766944, 44.838611)
my.long <- c(2.351944, 4.834167, 0.578334)

points <- data.frame(lon=my.long, lat=my.lat)

map <- get_map(location = c(left = -5, bottom = 42, right=9, top = 51 ), source = 'stamen', maptype = 'toner')
france <- ggmap(map, extent = 'normal')
france + geom_point(data=points, col="red")
```

[image]

Try the command `?ggmap` for a list of great examples. I think the manual has done a good job, because before I read your question, I didn't even know of any of these functions. Thanks! I've learned something new.

Answer (score 2):

Learn to walk before you try and run.

The `points` function adds points to an existing graphic. You haven't got an existing graphic yet (unless you've already done something you've not showed us).

Hence if you do `points` before starting a plot, you'll get an error. eg:

```
points(1:10,1:10) # plot.new error
plot(1:10,1:10) # no error, starts a new plot
points(10:1,1:10) # adds extra points, no error.
```

All your stuff with `ggplot` is irrelevant. Also, this is not about statistics, so you should have posted to StackOverflow. I've flagged this and it might get migrated...

Comment: Thanks for your help, @Spacedman, although points(10:1,1:10) still returns a plot.new error.